# Need to match at least 3 of given patterns in Regular Expression

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an application with MVC 4, razor. For one change Password view I need to do some validation which has following conditions:

It should match at least 3 of the following:

1. Upper case alphabetic characters

2. Lower case alphabetic characters

3. Numbers

4. Special keyboard characters (except script tags)

Now, I have written following regular expression in my model

```
[RegularExpression(&quot;^([a-zA-Z0-9#$%=@!{},`~&amp;*()'?.:;_|^/&#43;\&quot;-]{8,32})$&quot;, ErrorMessage = &quot;Current Password is invalid&quot;)]
```

but, this will match any of the given subsets. I need to match atleast 3 of them. Can anybody please help me how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be a good idea to use regex for password validation, but using lookaheads and the or operator `|` allows you to do this:

```
^(?:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[#$%=@!{},`~&*()'?.:;_|^/&#43;\"-])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#$%=@!{},`~&*()'?.:;_|^/&#43;\"-])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[#$%=@!{},`~&*()'?.:;_|^/&#43;\"-])).{8,32}$
```

---

There are 4 parts in this regex:

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])
```

Makes sure there's at least 1 lower alpha, 1 upper alpha and 1 number.

```
(?=.*[#$%=@!{},`~&*()'?.:;_|^/&#43;\"-])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])
```

Makes sure there's at least 1 special character, 1 upper alpha and 1 number.

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#$%=@!{},`~&*()'?.:;_|^/&#43;\"-])(?=.*[0-9])
```

Makes sure there's at least 1 upper alpha, 1 special character and 1 number.

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[#$%=@!{},`~&*()'?.:;_|^/&#43;\"-])
```

Makes sure there's at least 1 upper alpha, 1 lower alpha and 1 special character.

And using `|` with those four (grouped into a non-capturing group) gives you the 3 out of 4 validation.

Then use `.{8,32}` for the length of the password

Comment: Hi Jerry, Thank you very much. and I appreciate your response. but unfortunately, this regular expression is not working for me.
I also tried to put only first part, but still it did not work.
And as you have mentioned, validating password fields with regex may not be a good idea. Can you please suggest me a better way do the same?

Comment: @SuhaniMody What do you mean exactly by 'is not working for you'? Do you get any errors? The other way would be to check for each instance separately and something like, return 1 for each successful check, add the results of each and if it sums up to at least 3, the password will be valid.

Comment: Hi Jerry, I tried to put this first part as regular expression.
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]) , but it allowed any of upper alpha,lower alpha or number. not all of them.

Comment: @SuhaniMody Did you use the anchors? It's working [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/nM2dI2).

Comment: Yes @Jerry I used anchors when testing this separate or combined regular expressions.

Comment: @SuhaniMody Are you using `[RegularExpression("^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,32}$", ErrorMessage = "Current Password is invalid")]`? Because this regex should be working, otherwise, I believe there's something else not working.

Comment: Hi Jerry, Sorry, I don't know exactly what mistake I made before, but now it is working.. may be I did not escape some character, or I did not put it in proper format.. anyways, thanks a lot.. that helped me.. :)

Comment: @SuhaniMody No worries, I'm glad to have helped :)